# i18n Javascript Setup

Tags: javascript, jquery, localization, internationalization

I am trying to set up a simple dynamic page using i18n's javascript library. I am using their sample code of of their home page found here:

http://i18next.com/index.html

I can't get it to load the outlined json data, based on the sample html, javascript, and json code outlined below. Please let me know if there is a step, or a file naming convention I am missing.

home.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery.js" ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../i18next.js" ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul class="nav">
      <li><a href="#" data-i18n="nav.home"></a></li>
      <li><a href="#" data-i18n="nav.page1"></a></li>
      <li><a href="#" data-i18n="nav.page2"></a></li>
    </ul>
    <p>Test Paragraph</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

script.js

```
i18n.init(function(t) {
  // translate nav
  $(".nav").i18n();

  // programatical access
  var appName = t("app.name");
});
```

data.json

```
{
    "app": {
        "name": "i18next"
    },
    "nav": {
        "home": "Home",
        "page1": "Page One",
        "page2": "Page Two"
    }
}
```

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if not configured i18next will load resources with this schema:

```
locales/__lng__/__ns__.json
```

if no namespace is set it will use translation as namespace. so if you rename your data.json to translation.json and put it into the folder location/en (or whatever language you got) it should work.

more about initialization could be found here
http://i18next.com/pages/doc_init.html

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. This worked perfect. It wasn't clear that the default json file had to be named translation.json in that exact folder path if there wasn't a previously declared path.